# Scheduled notifications with AWS SNS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, push, amazon-sns

I'm developing an iOS app using AWS for the first time. Most things are straight forward, but I'm having trouble finding out how to schedule a push notification in the future. I'm currently using AWSSNSPublishInput to send a push immediately, but there doesn't appear to be any way to schedule the notification for some date-time in the future. I would just use UILocalNotification to schedule the future notification, but I need to schedule the notification for a different user.

For example, user A performs an action that user B needs to know about the next day.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) is designed to send notifications immediately. There is no functionality for scheduling notifications in SNS.

Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) does have a delay feature, but only up to 15 minutes -- this is useful if you need to do some work before the message is processed, such as copying related data to Amazon S3.

Given that, you need to schedule notification for some future time. you need to implement the logic yourself on server side like **database polling after some fixed interval of time** OR something like **job scheduler**.